# Is there a one-stop guide to choose a licence?

Tags: licensing, license-recommendation

Do you know of a guide that walks you through the choosing of a licence?

Comment: Question reformulated to hopefully be more on topic.

Comment: I do not think this is off topic. Even if this is about external resource, no single answer could reasonably provide a comprehensive answer.

Comment: @PhilippeOmbredanne do you mean it is not algorithmically possible to determine what licence a person should use with respect to their needs?

Answer (score 14):

That would be GitHub's [Choose a License tool](http://choosealicense.com/).

This wizard will let you choose what you're most concerned about - be it giving maximum freedom to your users, preventing patent claims, or ensuring that downstream developers can't remove user freedoms (i.e. [copyleft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyleft)).

As of this writing, there's 7 main licenses which this tool will help you compare. There's also [non-software options](http://choosealicense.com/non-software/) that it links to.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could expand on the benefits of this tool, even if it's just a sentence or two.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Point taken, and done :)

Comment: That's better than what I was hoping for! Take a +1 :)

Answer (score 5):

I found a few charts on a [Programmers Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/162136/192046) post:

[image: Chart one]

and this...

[image: Chart two]

---

The GitHub and Creative Commons licence choosers have their downsides. The CC chooser looks at non-software licences. The GitHub licence chooser isn't necessarily interactive - and only included a bunch of pre-selected "featured" licences.

There is also [this](http://oss-watch.ac.uk/apps/licdiff/) interactive licence chooser developed by OSS Watch, published by the University of Oxford.

Comment: @Zizou212 that's a decent basis. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

There is only one serious free libre and open source license wizard picker to pick a license and this is the work of [Dan Bentley](https://twitter.com/dbentley) and  [Brian Fitzpatrick](https://twitter.com/therealfitz) : 
[image: Which open source license?]

Comment: It's bothering me that you can't get to Lucent.

Comment: @TimMalone :D this is the plan9 island ;)

Comment: I am not sure the downvoters have any sense of humour.. sad.

Comment: Upvoted for the humour :)